# Can we exclude specific record in ToList() method in ADO.Net Entity Data Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.Net MVC with ADO.Net Entity Data Model.
When I use ToList() method, it select all records from table.

```
userEntity.USERs.ToList();
```

In this case, can I exclude specific record like "where" clause in SQL statement?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Where extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx).

Maybe something like:

```
userEntity.USERs.ToList().Where(user => user.UserId != 3456);
```

Comment: I believe that putting the where clause before the ToList will cause EF to generate the proper sql to only retrieve rows matching the where clause. The way you have it will pull back all the rows into memory, then filter on the where. check out Skeet's post on implementing linq to objects http://edulinq.googlecode.com/hg/posts/20-ToList.html

Comment: @MattPhillips: +1 Good observation and good answer. I just tacked on the Where extension to show its simplicity of use. You pointed out where a lot of LINQ/lambda n00bs get into trouble!

Answer (score 5):

try something like

```
userEntity.Users.Where(row => row.SomeColumn == SomeValue).ToList();
```

The `Where()` method will allow you to put constraints on the sql generated to retrieve the list like a Where clause in SQL.